# Set ASP.NET Core FormatterOptions JsonWriterOptions encoder from config

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-logging

I use ASP.NET Core json logging from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. I can configure encoder in code like this:

```
builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole(config =>
{
    config.JsonWriterOptions = new JsonWriterOptions { Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping };
});
```

But I don't understand why it doesn't work when I try to do the same thing by using only config:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "FormatterOptions": {
        "JsonWriterOptions": {
          "Encoder": "System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot set `Encoder` property this way because the default `Bind` implementation which binds `appsetting.json` values to an object doesn't bind static properties or anything else other than plain/collection values. A [custom logger provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider) might be useful in this case.

You can however set other `JsonWriterOptions` properties and you need to make sure to set `FormatterName` to `json`

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "FormatterName": "json",
      "FormatterOptions": {
        "JsonWriterOptions": {
          "Indented": true,
          "SkipValidation": true
        }
      }
    }
}
```